# How to Restructure/Translate Json objects to satisfy any schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema

I have a (long) json schema and I already validate the json objects in my code based on that schema. 
My problem/use-case is to translate/restructure an incoming json object to a new json object that satisfies my schema. 
I realized however, that it isn't that easy to do, especially if you look for an "adaptive" solution. 
Adaptive meaning that the code doesn't care about changes of the schema or the incoming object.

So my first approach was to create a class that contains a mapping of the incoming object to a valid object. 
This means however that I have to write this map by hand and update it if I change the schema.

So is there a solution where I can insert any schema, any non-valid (based on schema) json object and get a valid object out? 
Or at-least a way to generate a valid json object template, where you can insert the data of the incoming invalid json object?
This way I could at least be independent from schema changes.

PS: I tried to solve this problem in an abstract way, but if needed I can provide schema and the invalid object.
PPS: My environment is node.js.

Edit: E.g.: 
Schema

```
{
  ...//other Schema stuff (using draft-07) 
  "tokens": {
    "$id": "/token",
    "title": "Token",
    "description": "A representation of a word in a Message with all the nlp Analysis results and infos",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/tokens/definitions/token"
    },
    "token": {
      "$id": "#token",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "id",
        "text"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "description": "global (level:conversation) unique identifier to identify a token (cumulative)",
          "type": "number",
          "exclusiveMinimum": 0,
          "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "isText": {
          "description": "Describes if the token is a real semantic word or a whitespace or similar",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "text": {
          "description": "the actual content of the token",
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^(.+)$"
        },
        "word_index": {
          "description": "Index of a word in a text",
          "type": "number",
          "exclusiveMinimum": 0,
          "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "punctuation": {
          "description": "The punctuation that needs to be rendered before/after that token. TODO: finish it",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "characterOffsetBegin": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The inclusive character index in the sentence where this token begins"
        },
        "characterOffsetEnd": {
          "type": "integer",
          "description": "The exclusive character index in the sentence where this token ends"
        },
 "lemma": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "^(.+)$"
            },
 "pos": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": "part of speech tag",
              "pattern": "^(.+)$"
            },
      }
    },
    "text_label": {
      //This is where it gets difficult 
      "description": "Label of the text for the frontend. ",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "begin",
        "end"
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "description": "Name of the label",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "begin": {
          "description": "Token index where the label starts",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "end": {
          "description": "Token indes where the label ends",
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Object to translate:

```
{
  "text": "Hello, my name is Somebody. ",
  "sentences": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "word": "Hello",
          "originalText": "Hello",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 5,
          "before": "",
          "after": "",
          "pos": "UH",
          "lemma": "hello"
        },
        {
          "index": 2,
          "word": ",",
          "originalText": ",",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 5,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 6,
          "before": "",
          "after": " ",
          "pos": ",",
          "lemma": ","
        },
        {
          "index": 3,
          "word": "my",
          "originalText": "my",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 7,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 9,
          "before": " ",
          "after": " ",
          "pos": "PRP$",
          "lemma": "my"
        },
        {
          "index": 4,
          "word": "name",
          "originalText": "name",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 10,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 14,
          "before": " ",
          "after": " ",
          "pos": "NN",
          "lemma": "name"
        },
        {
          "index": 5,
          "word": "is",
          "originalText": "is",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 15,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 17,
          "before": " ",
          "after": " ",
          "pos": "VBZ",
          "lemma": "be"
        },
        {
          "index": 6,
          "word": "Somebody",
          "originalText": "Somebody",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 18,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 26,
          "before": " ",
          "after": "",
          "pos": "NN",
          "lemma": "somebody"
        },
        {
          "index": 7,
          "word": ".",
          "originalText": ".",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 26,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 27,
          "before": "",
          "after": "",
          "pos": ".",
          "lemma": "."
        }
      ],
      "basicDependencies": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: that this is corenlp analysis result that can change based on the annotator used.

Edit2: adding example of a correct object:

```
{ ...other parts of the object
   tokens:[
     { id:1, text: 'Hello', isText: true, word_index: 0, characterOffsetBegin:0, characterOffsetEnd: 5, lemma: 'hello', pos:'UH', ...}, 
      {...},
      {...}
   ],
   text_label:{
       name: 'joy', begin: 0, end: 3
   }

}
or another text_label: 
text_label:{
   name: 'PERSON', begin: 4, end: 5
}
```

Edit: Difference: 
As you can see, some changes a suttle like index->word_index, some are additional information like id, but some need a bit more like the text_label. 
corenlp. It could also happen that I need to unify 2 objects together. which is the case of the 'anger' text_label but isnt with the PERSON text_label.

So Im looking for some kind of json Object/Schema manager where translations, validations get easy and dont need hard coded mappings or the generation of that mappings is easy.

Comment: Currently it sounds like you're asking for something that's impossible. Can you please provide some more details with examples to narrow down the problem to something specific?

Comment: You might as well be asking for an automatic mapper from `{"a":"foo"}` to `{"monkey":["rabbit"]}`. My point being that the problem here isn't **just** about schema... There's domain specific knowledge that will drive this arbitrary schema translation, and you haven't told us a thing about it.

Comment: Writing an example now. I want to reduce the length and complexity a bit though.

Comment: @spender it goes into that direction yes.

Comment: I think that you can doo a foreach loop. First create the object without the json values, then foreach json values, set them as a object property..

Comment: There clearly isn't a cookie-cutter solution for this

Comment: Not only is this likely impossible, but it's highly likely something you SHOULD NOT do. If you do not know how the data structure will change, you cannot be sure any algorithm will apply the correct translation. You MAY make translation easier by using jq, although it has a steep learning curve. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ and you may find it less maintainable than "just writing the code"